# What is a more modern variant of the interjection 'Lo!"

Tags: single-word-requests, interjections

What is a more modern variant of the interjection 'Lo!"

I'm looking for a single word which has the same effect but is less archaic.

It is a very formal context I want to use it in that you may find in a courtroom for example: 'He claims he is innocent of corruption, but lo! He is guilty of taking bribes!"

Comment: Can you give us a sentence you'd be using it in?

Comment: _Behold_ is a millennium later on, but still archaic. How about _Lookit_?

Comment: It is a very formal context that you may find in a courtroom for example: 'He claims he is innocent of corruption, but lo! He is guily of taking bribes!"

Comment: We don't intone much in English these days. We're more about snarking.

Comment: I'm thinking "dude". He claims he is innocent of corruption, but dude he is totally taking bribes.

Comment: @Marcus_33 I would not use "dude" in a very formal context, which is what the OP wants.

Comment: @Chan-HoSuh, before I read the comments *dude* was the second word that occurred to me (after *behold*), except to make it formal I'd capitalize it and put an exclamation mark after it:  “He claims he is innocent of corruption, but Dude! he is totally taking bribes.”  *Whoa!* would have been pretty good too, but unfortunately that answer has been deleted.

Comment: @jwpat7 Probably the best is to *combine* those two: "He claims he is innocent of corruption, but... Whoa, dude!  He is taking bribes." :)  (I'm reminded of Bill and Ted...)

Comment: In a truly formal situation, I'd avoid anything that looked like an interjection and/or anything that involves an exclamation point. *"He claims he is innocent of corruption, but he is guilty of taking bribes."*

Comment: I have it on good authority that the modern equivalent of _lo!_ is the homoglyphic _lol_. _"He claims he is innocent of corruption, but lol, he is guilty of taking bribes!"_

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Historically, “lo!”, isn’t expressive of any particular emotion (*alas*) or addressed to any particular person (*dude*), and it's not an all-purpose interjection (*Hey*). It expressly calls upon hearers to look at, to take account of, to behold what follows.

In contemporary English we say **“look!”** in pretty much exactly the same way.

> He claims he is innocent of corruption, but look! He is guilty of taking bribes!

For that matter, so did Shakespeare. *Hamlet*, I, i, 40, the Ghost’s first appearance:

> *Marcellus*: Peace, break thee off; look, where it comes again!

And at the second appearance, 86 lines later

> *Horatio*: But soft, behold! lo, where it comes again!

Comment: Would have up voted and more, but for the fact that *Look* fails to bring the same kind of dramatic effect as *Lo*, not at all. Was *lo* used entirely in substitution of *look* in Shakespeare? Was *look* used as a verb and *lo* for an added interjective effect? (I am asking from a non-literary person's perspective, I don't know.)

Comment: @Kris  You can substitute *look* for *lo* anywhere it appears in Shakespeare without disturbing either the meaning or the register; *lo* is in effect an alternative form of the imperative. Witness the parallel passages above; or from *Macbeth*: *Prithee, see there! behold! look! lo!*  Even more interesting, from *Macbeth* again, and then from *Winters Tale: *Lo you, here she comes!*, and *Why, lo you now, I have spoke to the purpose twice*, both phrases which are ordinarily *look you*.

Comment: No way I could argue that *look* is of later usage than *lo*, which apparently is what the OP asked for. Plus, the reference in the question is (perhaps incorrectly) to an *interjection* not just a verb.

Comment: @Kris  Not to chop hairs, but OP says defines "more modern" as "a single word which has the same effect but is less archaic". And any bare imperative may have interjective force: *Behold!* *Go!* *Run!* *Fuck!*

Comment: @Kris  Oops ... chop logic, split hairs. Pick one!

Comment: "Lo" is short for lok "look!" imperative of loken "to look". Loken (third-person singular simple present loketh, present participle lokinge, simple past and past participle loked). Origin is Swedish, as imported by the Vikings. So @StoneyB get my vote.

Answer (score 4):

["Hey"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hey) seems to be in the modern idiom.
So,

"He claims he is innocent of corruption, but hey! He is guilty of taking bribes!"

Comment: In a more general situation, this might fit, but the OP was asking about a more formal context. "Hey" doesn't seem appropriate there.

Comment: @Lynn Contemporary usage: *Hey* could be as formal as *Lo*.

Comment: 'What do you know!' is perhaps in between formal and informal registers.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of possibilities, but none as satisfyingly interjective as *Lo!*

> He claims to be innocent of corruption, **but**, he is guilty of taking bribes.
>   He claims to be innocent of corruption, **yet**, he is guilty of taking bribes.
>   He claims to be innocent of corruption; **however**, he is guilty of taking bribes.
>   He claims to be innocent of corruption; **nevertheless**, he is guilty of taking bribes.
>   He claims to be innocent of corruption; **nonetheless**, he is guilty of taking bribes.
>   He claims to be innocent of corruption; **that notwithstanding**, he is guilty of taking bribes.

Comment: It may not be an interjection, but lo! I still like _nonetheless_ in this context.

Answer (score 1):

Consider  *[alas](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/alas#Interjection)* (Interjection, “Used to express sorrow, regret, compassion or grief”) and *[behold](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/behold#Verb)*.

> He claims he is innocent of corruption, but alas! He is guilty of taking bribes!

As noted in earlier comments, *behold* is a more modern form of *[lo](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lo#Interjection)* (Interjection, “(archaic) Look, see, behold”).  Whether *behold* is archaic (as John Lawler suggested) I can't say; wiktionary's “Usage notes” for it  say “Rarely used in informal speech.”

*Alas* also may seem archaic to some, but a few writers, including [Jerry Pournelle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerry_Pournelle), still use it frequently.  Note, *alas* (or *[alack](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/alack)*) expresses a note of regret, unlike either of  *behold* and *lo*, which bring with them overtones of  “I told you so”.

Comment: "Alas!" is certainly too literary even for a formal courtroom. Only writers, preachers, and other politicians can get away with using it.

Answer (score 1):

*Lo* as an interjection calls people to look at something, to behold it. *Behold* is rather archaic, and *look* as an interjection may not be quite as effective as ***See!***

> He claims he is innocent of corruption, but see! he is guilty of taking bribes.

There is an Advent hymn, "Lo, he comes with clouds descending", which loses some of its immediacy and portent if *Lo* is replaced with *Look*; but retains it if *See* is used.

Answer (score 1):

Lo in Hindi could be used to express frustration too: Like in the sentence, Lo chali gai bus. So, if there has to be one equivalent in English, I think it's SEE: However, one has to vary the tone when it expresses frustration.It's very colloquial as opposed to Shakespearean "lo" or behold which for that matter is archaic.